# Change title format of date while selecting

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker, react-widgets

[image]I am using Datetimepicker from react-widgets. I want to change the title of date cells, so that while hovering over the dates, I see the format I require. Currently, the title, and the date displayed in calendar footer is having format: `"Month Date, Year"`. I need to have `"Date Month, Year"`

I have tried using culture property. I am not sure if I tried correctly.

```
<DateTimePicker 
    inputProps={{ component: props => <input {...props} placeholder="Select year" /> }}
    dropUp
    time={false}
    max={new Date()}
    onChange={(e) => this.onSelect(e)}
    format="DD-MM-YYYY"
    culture='en-AU'
    editFormat="DD MMM, YYYY"
/>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for some solution in which I could avoid using JQuery. Now without any other solution I did this:

Created a custom datepicker:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DateTimePicker from 'react-widgets/lib/DateTimePicker';
import Moment from "moment";

export default class CustomDateTimePicker extends Component {

componentDidMount () {

 var datePickerbutton = document.getElementsByClassName('rw-btn-select');

 if (datePickerbutton.length) {
    var $this = this;
    datePickerbutton[0].onclick = () => {
        $this.changeTitles();
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementsByClassName('rw-calendar-btn-right')[0].onclick = $this.changeTitles;
            document.getElementsByClassName('rw-calendar-btn-left')[0].onclick = $this.changeTitles;
        }, 0);
    }
  }
}

changeTitles = () => {
 setTimeout(()=> {
    var primaryBtn = document.querySelectorAll('#createdOn-investigation .rw-calendar-footer .rw-btn-primary');
    primaryBtn[0].innerText = Moment(primaryBtn[0].innerText).format('DD MMMM, YYYY');
    var dateCells = document.querySelectorAll('#createdOn-investigation .rw-cell');
    for (var i=0; i< dateCells.length; i++ ) {
        let currCellDate = new Date(dateCells[i].getAttribute('title'));
        dateCells[i].setAttribute('title', Moment(currCellDate).format('DD MMMM, YYYY'));
    }
  }, 0);
};

render() {
 return (
  <DateTimePicker
    {...this.props}
    />
 )
}
```

}